# How to stop application , close Connection after reading 1000 messages in Spring Integration from a queue

Tags: spring-integration

How to stop application , close Connection after reading 1000 messages in Spring Integration from a queue.

I have used
 Message operation = (Message)MessageBuilder.withPayload("@servAct.stop()").build();
but this stops the channel, not the whole connection and application .

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide more info how you start the application. Maybe it will be just enough `System.exit(0)` for you?